# Surface texture type for mediacodec

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-mediacodec

Many examples of `mediacodec` use EXTERNAL `surfacetexture` as the output of `mediacodec`, my problem is can I use a 2D `surfacetexture`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

The output of SurfaceTexture is always `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES`, because it must accommodate a wide variety of color formats.  The output of MediaCodec is usually YUV, not RGB, making it a prime example.